# Upgraded Eclipse. Every app force closes

Tags: android, eclipse

I would be really grateful for some urgent advice:-

I was merrily building my apps (using eclipse) for Android platform 2.2. Everything all working lovely and ready to upload to the marketplace.

I thought I would try to install Google Play Licensing and in the process, I was told to download the LVL but that was not available in my SDK download list - and I read I had to updrage my SDK and ADT to the latest. So I did, I now have:

ADT 17.0.0 along with  ANDROID DDMS, hierarchy viewer  and Traceview at 17.0.0 with Eclipse IDE 1.4.2

And I also upgraded my SDK Android 2.2 stuff to the latest.

Now:-

I have no errors in my app workplaces on Eclipse.

But now when I run the apps, they build but force close straight away upon loading. This includes the app I was working on (and working perfectly before) and all the other apps I have ever made.

Every app now force closes and I dont know what to do. Been up all night and was ready to upload them to the market place... :(

Any help!? Thanks! Please!

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat for a typical force close.

Comment: Did you clean your projects ?

Comment: Yes I cleaned and refreshed the projects. Here is my stack trace I think (I havent used log cat before):


04-03 05:05:48.538: I/Process(698): Sending signal. PID: 698 SIG: 9
04-03 05:08:23.577: W/dalvikvm(765): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/microheroes/advice/advice; (351)
04-03 05:08:23.577: W/dalvikvm(765): Link of class 'Lcom/microheroes/advice/advice;' failed
04-03 05:08:23.587: D/AndroidRuntime(765): Shutting down VM
04-03 05:08:23.587: W/dalvikvm(765): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

Comment: And it continues: 

04-03 05:08:23.619: E/AndroidRuntime(765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 05:08:23.619: E/AndroidRuntime(765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.microheroes.advice/com.microheroes.advice.advice}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microheroes.advice.advice in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.microheroes.advice-1/pkg.apk]
04-03 05:08:23.619: E/AndroidRuntime(765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)

Comment: Ok here is a better way of displaying the logcat that I am seeing:

Comment: http://www.microheroes.com/images/log.txt  Please help, thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. What a ridiculous situation, 5 hours of life gone! But amazing to have it working again! Thanks so much for your help, perfect link, I wouldnt havt found that on my own. Thanks!!

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to "accept" it by clicking the icon to the left of the text (the icon will turn into green).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem however I resolved it by going to:
-Help
-Install New Software
-Click at the bottom right where it says "What is already installed?"

I had "Android Developer Tools" and "Android Development Tools" after the update.  Then I just deleted the oldest version.  That did it.  Sorry for my short explanation, English is not my first Language.